# Sorting nsfetchedresultscontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this structure in a entity of core data:

```
ID    Region    SubRegion   SubRegionID    CellText
1      Face      Mouth         2             something
2      Face      Eyes          1             ...
3      Face      Nose          4             ...
...
```

But I want my tableview (nsfetchedresultscontroller) sorted this way:

Inside each section: cells sorted by ID property
Sections in tableView: SubRegion names but sorted by SubRegionID.

How can I achieve this? By now I'm doing this but I don't know is the best practice to sort section titles by subregionID:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"DataBase" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(Region like '%@')", @"Face"]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];

NSSortDescriptor *ID = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"ID" ascending:YES];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ID, nil]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

fetchedResultsController  = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"SubRegion" 
                                               cacheName:nil];

fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some redundancy in your predicate. Rather than

```
NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(Region like '%@')", @"Face"]];
```

it should be just

```
NSPredicate *requestPredicate = 
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"Region", @"Face"];
```

It might also have to do with how you set up your `NSFetchedResultsController`. You should set the `sectionNameKeyPath` as "SubRegionID", not "SubRegion". In your `tableView datasource` method `titleForSection:` you should then return the name of the subregion based on the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But the problem still remains with the sorting logic I've used. I get cells sorted by ID but the section names aren't sorted by SubRegionID... I need face subregions (sections) sorted by subregionID and the cells inside those sections sorted by ID. Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It has to do with how you set up your `NSFetchedResultsController`. You should set the `sectionNameKeyPath` as `"SubRegionID"`, not `"SubRegion"`. In your `tableView datasource` method `titleForSection:` you should then return the name of the subregion based on the ID.

Comment: That's the way I used. But I thought it could be sorted using sortdescriptors directly. Thanks for your advice!